# Pack function arguments into a dictionary - opposite to **kwargs

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm trying to do something opposite to what **kwargs do and I'm not sure if it is even possible. But knowing Python it probably is :-).
I want to have all attributes clearly designed in my method (for auto completion, and ease of use) and I want to grab them all as, lets say a dictionary, and pass them on further.

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
      inputs = grab_function_inputs_somehow()
      self.bar(**inputs)
   
   def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
      pass
```

The normal thing to do is to assign each input into an object parameter but I don't want to do that for all classes. I was hoping for a way to wrap it to a method that can be inherited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create the dict with variables using [locals()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals). For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):    
        inputs = locals()
        del inputs['self'] # remove self variable
        print(inputs)

   
f = Foo()
```

Results in print out:

```
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's possible, but requires a little tweak to your code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, **inputs):
        # Have to set your defaults in here
        inputs['a'] = inputs.get('a', 1)
        inputs['b'] = inputs.get('b', 2)
        # Now the rest of your code, as you expected
        self.bar(**inputs)

    def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("bar got: %s" % kwargs)


# No arguments, use defaults
Foo()           # bar got: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
# Arguments provided
Foo(a=3, b=4)   # bar got: {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

So, instead of providing default arguments in the function definition, you're ensuring that the keys you expect exist, either with the provided argument, or with the defaults you pass as the second argument to `<dict>.get()`.

**Edit** `__init__` could also be written as:

```
def __init__(self, **inputs):
    # Have to set your defaults in here
    if 'a' not in inputs: inputs['a'] = 1
    if 'b' not in inputs: inputs['b'] = 2
    # Now the rest of your code, as you expected
    self.bar(**inputs)

# or

def __init__(self, **inputs):
    # Have to set your defaults in here
    args = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
    args.update(inputs)
    # Now the rest of your code, as you expected
    self.bar(**args)
```

Depending on the number of default arguments you have, the last option may be preferred.

Comment: that's what I have at the moment. The problem is I want explicit arguments in the __init__ to provide code completion and documentation for it.

Comment: @pawel Then `inputs = {'a':a,'b':b}` is usually what is done, but never the `locals()` approach -- its very kludgey imo.

Comment: I know. But in this case I'm writing an API and I want all arguments be declared in the __init__ explicitly to make them visible to users. To allow autocompletion to work for them etc. If I hide them inside a dictionary it will be difficult to catch mistakes early. Unless you know of any other approach to this problem.